# I got this "error missing $" in overleaf how can I solve it?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using `$\pi(x|D)=\exp(-\mathcal{U}(x))$` this expression in overleaf, but I got the error "missing $". The problem is using the symbol "|",  when I delete this character it works perfectly. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Assuming you're using LaTeX (as opposed to plain TeX), [it is preferred to not use `$` for math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode). Use `\( ... \)` instead (and `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$`, too). Doing that may give a more useful error message

Comment: @Andreas deniro Please include [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, just did a quick check in my local MiKTeX installation. The line does indeed compile just fine. You may have some missing packages, or an error elsewhere in your document. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    $\pi(x|D)=\exp(-\mathcal{U}(x))$
\end{document}
```

Comment: None of these packages is necessary for the code shown in the question. Please don't encourage users to load unnecessary packages. The more packages a user loads, the more likely they will run into some strange interactions between them.